# Make a generic delegate instance from a System.Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection, delegates

Is there a way to have a delegate instance of an open generic type parameter like so?

```
Action<T> SomethingHappened;
```

The compiler is giving me an error.

I might have asked this question every 2 years and forgotten. I can't find a previous similar question, so I am asking away anyway.

What I am really trying to do is this:

In Entity Framework, I want that whenever some new rows are added to a table or some data in existing rows of a table is modified, I want to write a generic framework of publishers that may tell any interested listeners that such and such a thing has happened.

For e.g. a publisher may tell all listeners interested in knowing about any new row additions to the **Customer** table or any modification in the **Customer** table.

The listeners might be loggers, emailers, etc.

Currently, what I am doing is a kludge, but I would like a more type-safe solution. Here's what I am currently doing:

```
 public partial class DaEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        Action<object, ObjectStateEntry> EntityModified;
        Action<object, ObjectStateEntry> EntityDeleted;
        Action<object, ObjectStateEntry> EntityAdded;

    public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
        {
            var modifiedEntities = 
                 ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                 System.Data.EntityState.Added | System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

            var deletedEntities = 
                 ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                 System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);

            foreach (var entry in modifiedEntities)
            {
                var type = GetObjectType(entry.GetType());

                // fire delegates here
            }

            return base.SaveChanges(options);
        }
    }
```

In the above scenario, I'd rather like to have something like this:

```
public static Action<T, ObjectStateEntry> EntityModified;
public static Action<T, ObjectStateEntry> EntityDeleted;
public static Action<T, ObjectStateEntry> EntityAdded;
```

And have them point to a generic method like so:

```
public void SomethingHappenedToAnEntity<T, ObjectStateEntry>
    (T t, ObjectStateEntry e)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you don't know what types may change (since the types returned from the calls to `ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries` calls are unknown at compile time), so you cannot provide an appropriate type for `T` when you call this method even if you were able to change the signature to accept an `Action<T>` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Having an undefined 'T' doesn't really make any sense... - what you really want is a custom event argument. You're going to have to force your types to be concrete at some point - so, you can either pass the parameter like:

```
Action<object> SomethingHappened;
```

And then have your code branch in the consuming method...

Or, you can cheat, and let dynamic dispatch try and figure out the types for you (at a small performance cost) - but this just pushes the problem around...

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic objectToProcess = new Moop();

    DoStuff(objectToProcess); //Dynamic dispatch will pick the best match automatically
}

public void DoStuff(Moop obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
}

public void DoStuff(Gloop obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
}

public void DoStuff(Bloop obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
}

public class Moop {}
public class Gloop {}
public class Bloop {}
```